# Notification when power source switches from AC to DC and back?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, power-management

I'm writing a Windows service using WinAPIs in C++. I'm curious if I can receive a notification when the system is switched from AC power (or plugged in) to DC power (or battery power) and vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PowerSettingRegisterNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh769082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  to register a callback function when the power state changes.  Then notification can queue up a call to [GetSystemPowerStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the AC/DC state.

There's also [WM_POWERBROADCAST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) notification message.

Comment: There is also [RegisterPowerSettingNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373196(v=vs.85).aspx), which is a different function...

Comment: @TonyK - thanks. I was just now looking up how to register a window handle for WM_POWERBROADCAST notificaitons. Problem solved.

Comment: Thank you both. I can make it work with `RegisterPowerSettingNotification` on Vista and later OS. But what about XP?

Comment: You might be out of luck with Windows XP. It seems that neither of these functions is supported.

Comment: @TonyK: Just found `PBT_APMPOWERSTATUSCHANGE` by accident. Could it be it for XP? I'm just not sure if it's broadcast for a service.

Comment: One thing to consider.  How likely is your customer going to be running Windows XP (an OS over 10 years old) on a battery powered device? I don't have definitive data, but it's possible that the majority of users still on XP are doing so on desktop machines.  If you believe that, you could consider not supporting power detection on XP. But you know your customers better than I do.

Comment: @c00000fd: I'm no expert, I'm afraid. But it seems that you need a window handle to receive these events.

Comment: I just tried and I can confirm that `PBT_APMPOWERSTATUSCHANGE` is broadcast for services as well. So it would work for XP.